# Why doesn't Erick Obsidian's schematic appear in my book?

Tags: arcanum-of-steamworks-and-magick

I have been given an ancient schematic by Erick Obsidian of the Wheel Clan for an Iron Key that unlocks the Place of Iron. When I right-click on it I get a notification that I have learnt the Iron Key Schematic, but it does not appear in any of the tabs of schematics (smithy, mechanical, etc).

- I have [UAP 091225](http://terra-arcanum.com/drog/dest/uap.html#091225) installed.
- I have no technological aptitude. (Apparently [this shouldn't be a problem](http://www.gamebanshee.com/arcanum/walkthrough/ironclan.php).)
- I am carrying mithril ore but no heartstone.

Where has the schematic gone? How can I make the key?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a bug. You don't need any expertise or affinity in order to learn this.

This is what you should have been seeing:

[image]

You should be able to open the relevant chest by using a fate point with **Cantrip of Unlocking** and setting it at maximum [(link)](http://www.terra-arcanum.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=135383#p135383).

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the screenshot. I have discovered that I cannot learn any Found Schematics, so I'm going to try a reinstall (with UAP 091225) as Eric B suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but it might be addressed [here](http://terra-arcanum.com/drog/dest/uap.html#091225). I think your best bet might be a reinstall and reloading the save, maybe after this patch. It should be showing up with your other schematics, not sure about the category (I think it's mechanics? Do you have any other mechanics schematics? Have you scrolled through the whole list?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I do have UAP 091225 installed (updated question with that info). I have looked through every page in every category, and nothing shows up. Other schematics (e.g. Bronwyck's Gun) are the same. Could it be because I have no points at all in any technological aptitude?